# Parse twitter short link out of string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse the link `'bit.ly/KATlrT'` out of : `asdfs asdf as dfa sdf a bit.ly/KATlrT f sf sd f dsfdsa`

This is the regex im using but it is not matching ?

```
bit?/S+
```

Comment: What is the language? And can you give some real input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(bit\.ly\/\S+)
^\ /^^\/^^\/^^
| | ||| ||| ||
| | ||| ||| |`- End first capture group
| | ||| ||| `-- Match 1 or more of previous (any non-space character)
| | ||| ||`---- Match any non-space character
| | ||| |`----- Match '/' literally because of previous escape character
| | ||| `------ Escape next special character
| | ||`-------- Match 'ly' literally
| | |`--------- Match '.' literally because of previous escape character
| | `---------- Escape next special character
| `------------ Match 'bit' literally
`------------- Start first capture group
```

**[See it in action.](http://rubular.com/r/onoXe6mtZO)**

---

Explanation for the one you supplied in your question:

```
bit?/S+
\/^^^^^
| |||||
| ||||`- repeat previous ('S') 1 or more times
| |||`-- match 'S' literally
| ||`--- this is not escaped, and will cause problems
| |`---- previous is optional ('t')
| `----- match 't' literally 
`------- match 'bi' literally
```

---

If you want to learn more about regular expressions, [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) is a great resource, and [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) or [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) are great tools for testing your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the language, I'll post the answer for Java regex (which is mostly based on Perl regex). There are quite a number of languages that follows more or less Perl's regex syntax.

```
"bit\\.ly/[a-zA-Z]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not matching probably because you forgot to escape `\S`, so it looks for a literal `S`. Also you'll need `.` instead of `?` in most languages.

Try `bit\.\S+` or `bit\.ly\/\S+`, etc.

Comment: `\S` can mean non-space character.

Comment: @nhahtdh that is what I mean, and the OP as well, I guess.